# How to set a timestamp as an initial value (0)

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, time, timestamp

I have a timestamp from a database and need to make a plot (rates vs time). I have the timestamps from when the process starts and ends, but I need to make the starting timestamp equal to 0 min (initial value) and the ending value equal to 20-30ish minutes (depending on the trial). I'm not sure what to use.

Also, I have the rates as a list and need to put them in an array for the matplotlib. I used np.asarray() and it says that the type is an array, but it is only giving me one number (the last number) on my plot. Any ideas on how to solve this?

code:

```
# timestamp comes out as 2.0080506043443555 e-16 because of the float
# need to change that into minutes for each run
L3time = L3timestamp.split()
del L3time[0]
for k in range(0, len(L3time)):
    print(float(L3time[k]))

#print("this is the L3 rates")
for k in range(1, len(L3time)):
    L3rate = (float(L3[k]) - float(L3[k-1]))*1000/(float(L3time[k]) - float(L3time[k-1]))
    print(float(L3rate))

# putting the L3 rate into an array
L3RateArray = np.asarray(L3rate)

# putting the timestamp into an array
timestampArray = np.asarray(L3time)


for k in inFile.readlines():
    plt.plot([timestampArray], [L3RateArray], 'ro')
    plt.xlabel("time (m)")
    plt.ylabel("L3 Rates (Hz)")
    plt.suptitle("L3 Rates vs. Time")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so we can help. Are your timestamps converted to datetime?

Comment: I added the code. I think the timestamps aren't converted to datetime because i turned it into a float

Comment: Your time stamp is `20080506043443555`? That is too large of a number to be a valid date. How is it defined?

Comment: It is supposed to be May 6th from 2008 at 4:34:43s and 555 milliseconds

Comment: Can you print `L3time`. It looks like an array of your elements of time that were just split up. Also matplotlib can use lists too, it does not have to be an array.